# MySQL Long Query Progress Monitoring

Tags: mysql, sql

Just to preface my question, I understand that there is no direct support for something like this. What I am looking for is any sort of work-around, or convoluted derivation that would get me a half-respectable result.

I am working with a rather large MySQL cluster (tables > 400 million rows) using the cluster engine.

Is anyone aware of a way to either <s>directly retrieve</s> or otherwise derive a somewhat (or better) accurate indication of progress through a long query in mysql? I have some queries that can take up to 45 minutes, and I need to determine if we're 10% or 90% through the processing.

**EDIT:**

As requested in the comments here is a distilled and generified version of *one* of the queries that is leading to my original question...

```
SELECT `userId`
FROM    `openEndedResponses` AS `oe`
WHERE
    `oe`.`questionId` = 3 -- zip code
    AND (REPLACE( REPLACE( `oe`.`value`, ' ', '' ), '-', '' ) IN ( '30071', '30106', '30122', '30134', '30135', '30168', '30180', '30185', '30187', '30317', '30004' ));
```

This query is run against a single table with ~95 million rows. It takes 8 seconds to run the query and another 13 to transfer the data (21 sec total). Considering the size of the table, and the fact that there are string manipulation functions being used, I'd say it's running pretty damn fast. However, to the user, it's still 21 seconds appearing either stuck or idle. Some indication of progress would be ideal.

Comment: One single query is taking up to 45 minutes, or is it a lot of small INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries ?

Comment: KOGI, if you were able to solve your problem you should add it as an answer.

Comment: I was not able to solve my problem. Hence the +1 for everyone :)

Comment: Can you post us the query that's taking so long???  Maybe IT can be optimized better...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as it contains sensitive corporate data, but maybe I can distill it a bit for public viewing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now -- for my very specific situation -- there seems to be no real solution for this. Since I can't split my query into several smaller ones and it's proving counterproductive to `select count(*)` first, and then running the "real" query (doubles execution time of an already painfully slow query), none of the workarounds seem viable either. Maybe soon, MySQL will support something like this

Comment: Why do you `select count(*)`?

Comment: This is really old now, but `COUNT(*)` was a way to determine how many rows there would be in order to chunk the query into multiple smaller queries.

Answer (score 55):

I know this is an old question, but I was looking for a similar answer, when trying to figure out how much longer my update would take on a query of 250m rows.

If you run:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS \G
```

Then under TRANSACTIONS find the transaction in question, examine this section:

```
---TRANSACTION 34282360, ACTIVE 71195 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
1985355 lock struct(s), heap size 203333840, 255691088 row lock(s), undo log entries 21355084
```

The important bit is "undo log entries". For each updated row, in my case it seemed to add an undo log entry (trying running it again after a few seconds and see how many have been added).

If you skip to the end of the status report, you'll see this:

```
Number of rows inserted 606188224, updated 251615579, deleted 1667, read 54873415652
0.00 inserts/s, 1595.44 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 3190.88 reads/s
```

Here we can see that the speed updates are being applied is 1595.44 rows per second (although if you're running other update queries in tandem, then this speed might be separated between your queries).

So from this, I know 21m have been updated with (250m-21m) 229m rows left to go.

229,000,000 / 1600 = 143,125 seconds to go
(143,125 / 60) / 60 = 39.76 hours to go

So it would appear I can twiddle my thumbs for another couple of days. Unless this answer is wrong, in which case I'll update it sometime before then!

Comment: Ahh, think I'm just making noise with this, for some reason I'd thought this was about an update, rather than select query

Comment: Your noise was very useful for estimating the runtime of my DELETE statement, so thanks a bunch! It seems that "row lock" is also a very good number to look at, I suspect it tells you how many rows (of all involved tables) the query has looked at so far while the "undo log" is how many it has changed.

Comment: i was looking for this, what a useful noise

Comment: The \G didn't work for me, it produces a syntax error.  Perhaps I'm on an older version of mysql?

Comment: For me, undo log count and row locks count reset periodically. I am adding a column to a huge table. It says "copy to tmp table". The end of the report row operations seem to be a db cumulative running total.

Comment: This is very useful, although depending on where you are running the query you probably have to remove the \G

Comment: I'm replacing into table a using the inner join result of table b/c on a unique id of both tables. Table b/c has ~2.4m rows, now I observe 12m row locks and 2.5m undo logs for this tx, yet the tx is not completed. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10):

There is a promising answer to this old question which I found [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/04/22/how-to-estimate-query-completion-time-in-mysql/), written by Baron Schwartz. It's not a precise and complete solution, but it does provide some objective material for estimates, **if you're only running that query and nothing else on your server**.

You run this command *while the query is already running*:

```
mysqladmin extended -r -i 10 | grep Handler
```

- that `10` is the number of seconds after which the command repeats itself, so wait for the refreshes
- add something like `-u root -p` if you need to authenticate
- if you know exaclty which Handler you're looking for, you can make the `grep` more focused, for example `Handler_read_rnd_next` seems to be good for `SELECT`'s
- ignore the first output, use the second and following
- use `Ctrl-C` to exit

Now get that number and **do your math**. Determine rows handled per second, and with your knowledge of table sizes you might be able to get a fairly precise estimate of total time.

Free extra tip: the command doesn't seem to go into Bash history (maybe because of the exiting with `Ctrl-C`, you can add it there by hand with `history -s mysqladmin extended -r -i 10 -u root -p | grep Handler`

Comment: This is brilliant and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I was able to identify the delete speed by observing Handler_delete using this method.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to estimate something like this by querying the number of rows to process then breaking the processing into a loop, working on only a subset of the total rows at a time.

The full loop was rather involved, but the basic logic went like:

```
SELECT @minID = Min(keyColumn) FROM table WHERE condition
SELECT @maxID = Max(keyColumn) FROM table WHERE condition
SELECT @potentialRows = (@maxID - @minID) / @iterations

WHILE @minID < @maxID
BEGIN
    SET @breakID = @minID + @potentialRows
    SELECT columns FROM table WITH (NOLOCK, ...)
    WHERE condition AND keyColumn BETWEEN @minID AND @breakID

    SET @minID = @breakID + 1
END
```

Note this works best if IDs are evenly distributed.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this correctly, you perform the query once to get the minId, once again for the maxId, and then a 3rd time (comprised of multiple chunked sub-queries)? While this would definitely offer some indication of progress, it effectively triples the total query time (at minimum, doubles it if you combine determination of min and max into a single query). What am I missing?

Comment: @KOGI: Provided the column for which you are calculating the MIN/MAX value on is indexed, you should have to inspect something like CEIL(LOG2(rows)) total rows -- taking significantly less time.  If that column isn't indexed, it probably should be if your SELECT is based on it, and you're going to have to eat the downtime to add that index now that your table is huge...

Comment: Thanks, Conspicuous Compiler. I like this idea and so far it's the best option I've come across. I wonder what the performance impact would be (ignoring the determination of MIN/MAX) to run several chunked queries versus one large query...

Comment: Yes, `keyColumn` should be indexed and, in my situation, the time to determine the Min and Max was negligible. Depending on the full query and execution plan it could take less or more time to perform than a single query. Only profiling can determine how well it works for you.

Comment: +1 Can't accept any of these answers as a solution, but the ideas and effort is still appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

<s>I don't think that mysql supports</s> I'm sure MySQL doesn't support any indication about the progress of the running queries. The only solution is to optimize/split queries.
Select could be split by id as Dour High Arch suggested. Here is a query from 33 milion row table:

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE min(id), max(id) FROM `urls`;
+---------+----------+
| min(id) | max(id)  |
+---------+----------+
|    5000 | 35469678 |
+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You better use integer ot at least date field for splitting. It should be **primary** or **unique** index and should not allow null values.

Comment: +1 Can't accept any of these answers as a solution, but the ideas and effort is still appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If your query involves a linear scan through a large table, you can often obtain an excellent estimate by running [pmonitor](https://github.com/dspinellis/pmonitor) on the file containing that table. Include the `--update` option, because *MySQL* opens table files in update mode.

### Example:

```
$ sudo pmonitor --update --file=/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD --interval=5

/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD 31.66%
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD 33.16% ETA 0:03:42
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD 34.85% ETA 0:03:24
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD 36.43% ETA 0:03:32
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD 38.36% ETA 0:03:12
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD 40.21% ETA 0:03:01
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD 41.95% ETA 0:02:54
[...]
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD 92.01% ETA 0:00:24
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD 93.85% ETA 0:00:18
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD 95.76% ETA 0:00:12
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD 97.60% ETA 0:00:07
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD 98.83% ETA 0:00:03
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/commits.MYD 100% ETA 0:00:00
```

If you don't know the file to monitor, run *pmonitor* with the --diff option.  This will show you the file(s) where progress is made.

### Example

```
$ sudo pmonitor --update -diff --command=mysqld -i 60
[...]
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/projects.MYD      22.41% ETA 2:01:41
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/projects.MYD      23.13% ETA 1:53:23
/home/mysql/ghtorrent/projects.MYD      23.84% ETA 1:50:27
```

Comment: `The pmonitor command will display the progress of a process as a percentage. It does this by examining the process’s open files, and calculating the ratio between the position of the file’s seek pointer offset and the file length. For processes that process files in a sequential fashion, such as file compression and database import, this ratio can be translated to the percentage of the job that has been completed.` - wow, it's a really cool idea!

Answer (score 2):

If it's a complex query you are attempting, the EXPLAIN SQL command or MySQL Query Analyzer might help to understand what is going on.  If it's simply a large query, you might try creating a temporary table with SELECT INTO and/or using LIMIT/OFFSET clauses in SELECT queries.  If you use LIMIT/OFFSET on the original tables, you might need to set the transaction level to serializable, IIRC, so that you get consistent reads while iterating over the data.  If you create a temporary table first, that table should stay consistent regardless.

Comment: +1 Can't accept any of these answers as a solution, but the ideas and effort is still appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you'll need to do to improve the following query:

```
SELECT `userId`
FROM    `openEndedResponses` AS `oe`
WHERE
    `oe`.`questionId` = 3 -- zip code
    AND (REPLACE( REPLACE( `oe`.`value`, ' ', '' ), '-', '' ) IN ( '30071', '30106', '30122', '30134', '30135', '30168', '30180', '30185', '30187', '30317', '30004' ));
```

You'll need to ensure oe.questionId is indexed;
You'll need to ensure oe.value does not have any space across the entire table when oe.questionId is 3; assuming that 4 or 5 can be, let's say, city names, where you still want to allow spaces.

By doing this, you'll be able to remove all the REPLACEs , which will let MySQL use an index in oe.value.

MySQL will then merge both indices and give you the result much faster, in terms of processing.

In the case you have many repeated userId; you'll want to group them; in such a way that entries from the index are immediately discarded. You still need to scan the whole merged-index; but the size of the resultset will take less time to be transferred; much less than 13 seconds!

Give it a shot and keep us posted about the result

Best!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This question is really old now, but this definitely has potential for speeding up the queries themselves. However, regardless of speed, what I was looking for was a way to monitor progress. There are some queries that just plain aren't fast, and can't be optimized any further -- I needed a way to see the progress of the query execution as it ran.

Answer (score 0):

How about looking into partitioning your mysql table so you can spread the read/write load. Look at trying to limit each partition to 50 Million rows (obviously dependent on your hardware)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This definitely has potential for speeding up the queries themselves, but regardless of speed, what I was looking for was a way to monitor progress.

Comment: Ar! Now I re-read your question Ill have a think. It was a quick response on the way into work :)

Comment: in the back of my mind im thinking if you split your tables into partitions and even if possible, break them into separate tables, you could make your query perform so much quicker, you wouldnt have to worry about monitoring... we (being so) could look at how best to partition, index, your tables to perform much quicker if you give us the columns and read/write functions you need to perform.