# Mysql query progress bar with php and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

A basic Bootstrap progress bar looks like this:

```
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
   aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
     70%
   </div>
</div>
```

How could I update in real time the percentage values, based upon the progress of a **Mysql SELECT** query that takes from a few seconds up to a minute to finish.

I´m using php for the application.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. A work around that comes to mind is to query parts of data set (table) in a loop and on each iteration send a response.

Comment: Not sure, depends on several things. Wait for some mysql experts to respond. Interesting idea though, I would use something like this myself for some projects.

Comment: Show us what is going on on php side? what query are you trying to get? is it really slow? is there data transformation part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Looks like [this is possible](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/progress-reporting/) with MariaDB 5.3+ now. anyway, I wouldn't suggest doing this because you'll use vendor-specific extensions.

Referring to [MySQL Long Query Progress Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464931/mysql-long-query-progress-monitoring), it isn't possible to monitor a MySQL query. The only thing you could do is to split queries and then check how many queries ran through already.

Comment: @caCtus, now it should fit

Comment: It's possible with MariaDB now: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/progress-reporting/